# Asp.net Core with Angular 2 main.js Path Error

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-core-1.1

I am building asp.net core application with Angular 2 with the help of Angular Quickstart.

Since Asp.Net core application allows wwwroot as a folder, I moved all the dependencies to that folder including node modules.

**Layout.cshtml**:

```
    <script src="/node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

    <script src="~/src/systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.import('main.js').catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });
    </script>
```

**ts.Config.json** :

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "outDir": "wwwroot/src"

  }
}
```

Now I am facing below error:

> http://localhost:18929/main.js 404 (Not Found)
>   (index):45 Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:18929/main.js

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding the following in the header of the html

```
<base href="/" />
```

Comment: This link can help you to solve the error. http://asp.net-hacker.rocks/2016/04/04/aspnetcore-and-angular2-part1.html